# purpose of file in ubuntu

Tags: 10.04

There are lots of important file in ubuntu . But, how can I learn which  file is for what ? In other words, I want know why they is used for. Where can I learn the purpose of file in ubuntu ?

Ex

```
 /var/cache/apt/archives is for what ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:

http://www.tuxradar.com/content/take-linux-filesystem-tour

It covers most (if not all) of the important root directories in UNIX-Like systems, and should help you understand what they're all for.

Answer (score 1):

To learn about the purpose of directories in Ubuntu you may find the specifications outlined in the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) useful. These are valid for any Debian based Linux distribution.

See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16521/where-in-the-filesystem-should-i-store-shared-data) with quite nice answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no one place that holds that information.  Google is probably the best place to start for any particular file or directory which you are interested in.  For example googling for /var/cache/apt/archives you would soon work out what it is for.